# "service {FOO} start" vs. "/etc/init.d/{FOO} start"?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, services, init.d

I use CrashPlan on my Debian 8 desktop.  I have a script where I must stop the CrashPlan service at the beginning and then start it before exiting.  I was using

```
/etc/init.d/crashplan start
```

for the restart but the new CrashPlan process was exiting at the termination of **my** script.  I switched to

```
service crashplan start
```

and all is well!

<strike>Oddly, under Ubuntu 16.04 on another box, the `init.d` script/command behaves as desired.  When my script exits, CrashPlan continues to run.</strike> **Welp, now Ubuntu is giving me the same issues.**

My Debian script is now functional.  But I was under the impression that the `service` command was on the way to deprecation, so I am puzzled by the differences, both between `init.d` and `service`, <strike>and between the current releases of Debian and Ubuntu.</strike>

Comment: Actually I think the question was clear enough to garner a very good answer, so if it needs to go away that would be a shame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On any system using systemd, running an init.d script directly won't be the best way to start a service, since it will bypass all settings and bookkeeping usually done by systemd itself. Also, you might not even have an init script, the service might be described only in a unit file.

With "old-style" sysvinit there was not much bookkeeping to do: starting a service was about the same as just running a script. That doesn't mean it was a good idea to the init script directly, the description in the man page of `service` tells you why:

> `service` runs a System V init script or upstart job in as
>   predictable an environment as possible, removing most environment
>   variables and with the current working directory set to /.

A random shell is not a very predictable environment, you could have e.g. file or process limits active.

As for deprecation, perhaps you should use `systemctl`, but on Debian `service` actually tries to do the right thing and runs `systemctl` for you. (Let's just say that if `service` is deprecated, then running an init script directly is even more so.)

(I'm not enough of a systemd expert to tell you what exactly kills the service if you run the init script directly. That also depends on what runs the script you are running: from cron, from the command line, from something else...)